# R: Reshape time series data into feature vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a huge dataframe with almost 1 million rows. The dataframe consists of observation of two values, here denoted with **a** and **b**. The dataframe is the result of a join operation between these two measurements. Therefore an **is_a** and **is_b** column denotes where the measurement comes from. For each timestep, I want to aggregate the last **n** values of **a** and **b**. If less then **n** values are available `NA` is used. That is, if only one value is available for `a`, `a_t1` as well as `a_t2` are `NA`. Only `a_t3` does hold data. For each of these values, a tdiff is given, denoting the time in hours between the current and previous step. Of course the operation should work on group-level. Example data:

```
df <- tibble(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Time = c(as.POSIXct("1900-01-01 10:00:00"), as.POSIXct("1900-01-01 14:00:00"), as.POSIXct("1900-01-01 15:00:00"), as.POSIXct("1900-01-01 17:00:00"), as.POSIXct("1900-01-01 20:00:00")), a = c(NA, 1, 2, NA, 3), is_a = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1), b = c(1, NA, NA, 3, 1), is_b = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1))
# A tibble: 5 x 6
     ID Time                    a  is_a     b  is_b
  <dbl> <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 1900-01-01 10:00:00    NA     0     1     1
2     1 1900-01-01 14:00:00     1     1    NA     0
3     1 1900-01-01 15:00:00     2     1    NA     0
4     1 1900-01-01 17:00:00    NA     0     3     1
5     1 1900-01-01 20:00:00     3     1     1     1
```

I have a working solution iterating over every timestep using purrr and selecting the relevant rows from the data. However this is very slowly for big datasets. Here is my solution:

```
aggregate_df <- function(use_data) {
  ret <- use_data %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(obs = purrr::pmap(.l = list(Time, ID), .f = function(curr_t, id) {
      df1 <- compute_lagged_sequence(., id, curr_t, "a", "is_a")
      df2 <- compute_lagged_sequence(., id, curr_t, "b", "is_b")
      return(tibble(df1, df2))
    })) %>%
    unnest(obs) %>%
    select(-a, -is_a, -b, -is_b)
  return(ret)
}

compute_lagged_sequence <- function(use_data, id, curr_t, col_to_use, reference_col, n = 3) {
  rel_rows <- filter(use_data, ID == id) %>%
    filter(Time <= curr_t) %>%
    filter(.data[[reference_col]] == 1) %>%
    slice_tail(n = n) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(Time, !!col_to_use) %>%
    mutate(!!sym(sprintf("%s_tdiff", col_to_use)) := as.double.difftime(curr_t - Time, units = "hours")) %>%
    select(-Time) %>%
    summarise(cur_data()[seq(n), ]) %>%
    arrange(!is.na(.data[[col_to_use]]), desc(!!sym(sprintf("%s_tdiff", col_to_use)))) %>%
    mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = row,
                values_from = c(!!col_to_use, !!sym(sprintf("%s_tdiff", col_to_use))))
  return(rel_rows)
}

aggregate_df(df)
     ID Time                  a_1   a_2   a_3 a_tdiff_1 a_tdiff_2 a_tdiff_3   b_1   b_2   b_3 b_tdiff_1 b_tdiff_2 b_tdiff_3
  <dbl> <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1 1900-01-01 10:00:00    NA    NA    NA        NA        NA        NA    NA    NA     1        NA        NA         0
2     1 1900-01-01 14:00:00    NA    NA     1        NA        NA         0    NA    NA     1        NA        NA         4
3     1 1900-01-01 15:00:00    NA     1     2        NA         1         0    NA    NA     1        NA        NA         5
4     1 1900-01-01 17:00:00    NA     1     2        NA         3         2    NA     1     3        NA         7         0
5     1 1900-01-01 20:00:00     1     2     3         6         5         0     1     3     1        10         3         0
```

The idea behind this structure is that I want to use a machine learning model that always get's the last n data points of each observation along with some time reference in hours.
Any idea how to speed things up?